# Should I turn these images into a sprite, and if so, how would I do so? (picture included)

Tags: asp.net, css, performance, sprite

I have an asp.net (vb) website with a clients page. On that page, there are hyperlinked logos to some of our larger clients.  Each logo is identical in size (w 207 h 119).  There are 3 columns and 5 rows of images, so 15 logos in total.

Currently, the images are coded like this -- but I'm thinking I need to remove the asp images and just use regular images:

```
<td>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink15" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/clgm.jpg" 
NavigateUrl="http://www.gm.com" Target="_blank"    
itemprop="url">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
</td>
<td>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink16" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/clford.jpg" 
NavigateUrl="http://www.ford.com" Target="_blank" 
itemprop="url">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
</td>
```

And so on, for all 15 clients.  Would it be better for speed and performance (by reducing http requests if I sprited these images into one image?  Assuming that's the case, should I **change these asp:hyperlinks and asp:images to just regular html links and images**?  And then how would I sprite them?  I'm not too good with css, so I'd truly appreciate any help anybody can offer in this regard.

If needed, below is what they look like -- again, 3 columns and 5 rows (**that's where I get even more confused**):

[image]

Comment: have a look at http://spriteme.org/

Comment: Hey @Pleun!  Thank you for the link!  I'll definitely check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sprites are good.
Having your sprite image is most of the work in my opinion.

You can now access your sprite with a bit of css.
See here for working example.
http://jsfiddle.net/DWy2W/

```
<style>
.sponsor{
    width:80px;
    height:50px;
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m93cd.jpg);
}
.gm{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.ford{
    background-position: -80px 0px;
}
.osi{
    background-position: -80px -50px;
}​
</style>
<a href="http://www.ford.com">
    <div class="sponsor ford"></div>
</a>
<a href="http://www.gm.com">
    <div class="sponsor gm"></div>
</a>
<a href="http://www.osi.com">
    <div class="sponsor osi"></div>
</a>​
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge, @Bill MaGriff!  And thank you especially for the fiddle.  I'm fiddling around with it myself just to give me an idea on how the .css x and y values are affecting what's shown.  I really do appreciate your time and efforts in helping me out with this issue!

Comment: Bill, would you recommend using tr's or td's, or ul's and li's?

Comment: Got it, @Bill MaGriff ... I just used a table with 1 row and 3 td's, and used ul/li's in those columns.  Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be better for speed and performance (by reducing http
>   requests if I sprited these images into one image?

Yes, it would be a general performance increase.  One image loaded vs fifteen is a big overall HTTP request savings.

> Assuming that's the case, should I change these asp:hyperlinks and
>   asp:images to just regular html links and images?

Is that ASP code there for a reason?  Is it converting the HTML between development/production servers?  If not, I don't really see much need to process a simple HTML link so it would save whatever few milliseconds of processing to convert it into HTML.

> And then how would I sprite them?

[CSS-Tricks.com has a good sprite tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).
[A List Apart also has a good sprite article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).

In general, you would do something like this:

1. Give each `IMG` tag an ID such as `id="logo-gm"`
2. In CSS, give each sprite a width/height (this could be made easier by applying this at a container level)
3. Give each unique ID the background of the sprite image and position so that the proper logo appears.

Your CSS might look like this but your actual CSS needs will depend on your own site design:

```
.logo-sprites img { 
  width: 207px, 
  height: 119px; 
}
#logo-gm{ 
  background: url(/path/to/img/logo-sprite.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
}
#logo-ford{ 
  background: url(/path/to/img/logo-sprite.png) no-repeat -207px 0; 
}
```

Your HTML might look something like this:

```
<ul class="logo-sprites">
    <li><img id="logo-gm" alt="GM Logo" /></li>
    <li><img id="logo-ford" alt="Ford Logo" /></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

For the background CSS:

```
background: url(/path/to/img/logo-sprite.png) no-repeat -207px 0;
```

the `-207px` represents the 'x' value and you subtract the width to move the image to the next virtual column.  The `0` represents the 'y' value of a 2D plane and you subtract the height to move to the next row.  Starting from the top left corner is point (0,0).

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hey @jimbertucci!  As I told kxb, although I'm always looking for an easy, lazy way out ... hehe ... I'm going to try his auto-generate sprite thing, but I'm going to hard-code it per your suggestions, and the suggestions @Bill MaGriff used in the fiddle he provided.  You have definitely cleared things up and explained it to me like the css novice I am!  I now understand how the css is calling which part of the image sprite and where to display that part of the sprite, per the x and y values.  Thank you for taking the time and effort to explain things so clearly; I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Jim, are ul's and li's a better way to go than tr's and td's?

Comment: I figured it out ... thanks to your explanations.  Thanks again for taking the time to offer the information @jimbertucci!

Comment: @JasonWeber Glad I could offer some help!  We all have to start somewhere. =)

Comment: @JasonWeber Sorry, I didn't think you were talking to me. My name's actually John.  But I see were "jm" in my screen name can look like "Jim". =) If you're just displaying a list of logos, it's better to use a `UL`/`LI` element as that represents a list.  Table elements are used to display tabular data. This is part of the "web standards" movement of using semantically important element.  However, you don't even has to use a list.  They could be individual `DIV` or `SPAN` or `A` elements, depending on your need.  It's pretty common to use lists though (as it's a list of names/logos).

Comment: Thank you John .... will not call you Jim anymore!  But yes, I used to think that the ul/li won't work with style="display:inline" would work for these types of things, but I think just old-fashioned tr's and td's work better in more browsers.  Thanks again for taking the time to respond!

Comment: Hi @JasonWeber You have to fairly good option to display them horizontally.  A) Float the list elements `li{ float:left; }` and clear the container the float is in with the "[clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)" method. B) Use `display:inline-block`.  IE7 doesn't support it but there are [fixes for IE7 inline-block](http://uncorkedstudios.com/2011/12/12/how-to-fix-the-ie7-and-inline-block-css-bug/).  I hope that helps! =)

Comment: Thanks John; I actually developed my first 2 sprites on notepad earlier with no WYSIWYG or anything ... so I think I'm getting the hang of it!  Appreciate the knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely good idea to reduce the number of http requests. In your case if you use sprites you are basically reducing 15 http request to 1. You don't have to use any image tag for this, you can use some div or li and use the background-image css property to specify the image. All the elements need to have different css class name and each class with specific background-position. Check this article  http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Thank you, @Tariqulazam.  I have that website bookmarked, but I'm going to give it another look -- because now that I've read what you and others have had to say about this, maybe I'll understand it a little more clearly.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Sprites are definitely useful given the number of them and the standard size of the images. As noted in other answers, it is not going to hurt you for sure!

To generate sprites, there are number of online options available like http://spritegen.website-performance.org/

In VS.NET, you can use the [CssSpriteGenreator](http://nuget.org/packages/CssSpriteGenerator) or [Talifun.web.CssSprite](http://nuget.org/packages/Talifun.Web.CssSprite) NuGet

Comment: Hello @kxb!  Thank you very much for the links; I've already checked them out, and I'm going to give them a try.  I'm also going to hard-code it per suggestions by @jimbertucci, but I'm going to use this too, and see how they compare -- and hopefully improve my (lack of) knowledge of CSS.  Thank you for taking the time to respond!